# Commit message with git-commit-id-maven-plugin (Springboot)

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin

I use git-commit-id-maven-plugin exposed git infos with commit message to info endpoint with my Springboot project, but the commit message not appear. Any ideas?

Here is how i tried:

```html
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/../.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <includeOnlyProperties>
                        <includeOnlyProperty>git.commit.message.full</includeOnlyProperty>
                    </includeOnlyProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```